# Firebase user import / export

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Does anyone know how to migrate users from one firebase project to another and keep the same `uid` ?

Ideally the `uid` would be the same in the target project since I have in the db tied records to the `uid`

Is it possible to keep the `uid` the same in target project ?

The source project would then be deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the specific `auth:export` and `auth:import` commands of the [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth):

- The `auth:export` command exports user accounts to JSON and CSV files.
- The `auth:import` command imports user accounts into Firebase projects.

Comment: Ok, the migrated user will have the same uid in the target project, when the user then logs in it will not create a new user (with the same username) with a different uid but use the existing one ?

Comment: According to this the uid is different between projects for same Google credential,
see "Sharing UIDs Between Projects", 
https://firebase.blog/posts/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app

Comment: As shown in the doc referred to in the answer, when you import users into a project [you can define their UIDs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#file_format), cf. first column. So you can very well keep the same UIDs across the two projects, and yes, "when the user then logs in it will not create a new user (with the same username) with a different uid but use the existing one".